# What is the exact definition of the Universal Gas Constant $R$? One that gives the reason for every formula that has the idea of this constant

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, history, physical-constants

We find that $R$ can be derived in many different ways through various relations. Its born out of the concept of an **Ideal Gas**. However what definition can clearly justify all of the relations based on $R$, and also include the justification for the assumptions on which it is based?

Also in reality, how exactly was the concept of $R$ born? Like what led to it?

Answer (score 2):

The ideal gas constant is not a physical quantity, it is an artifact of your choice of units. In SI units its value is **exactly**: $R = 8.31446261815324 \text{ J/(K⋅mol)}$. The fact that the value is exact is a big hint that this is not a physical quantity but rather just the result of the definition of the SI units.

What $R$ does is it relates our scales of temperature and energy, just like Boltzmann's constant, except that it does it on a per-mole basis (another scale) rather than a per-particle basis. It tells us that the SI committee made the kelvin about 8 times bigger than the joule/mole. In natural units the temperature scale would be the same as the energy/amount scale, but SI units are not natural.

The only thing that justifies the use of $R$ in all of those formulas is that they are expressed in some units that, like SI, require the conversion. If they were written in some form of thermodynamic natural units then $R$ would disappear from all of the equations.